# MD5 the id in URL and get the id to other page using PHP

Tags: php, security

Suppose that I have code as below:

```
<td><a href="view_edit_form.php?id=<?php echo md5($row[0]);?>">Edit</a></td>
```

And in page `view_edit_form.php` I get the id by using this code `$ID = $_GET['id'];`

**The problem**

I can not get the `id` if I `md5` it like this.Anyone help me please, Thanks.

Comment: does `$row[0]` have a value before md5?

Comment: what do you mean you cannot get the id? does `$_GET['id']` does not have a value? or you cant get the id because you cannot decode the `md5`? please elaborate what your are getting.

Comment: A `md5()` isn't reversible, you can only find strings which hash to it.

Comment: Why not just send the id instead of `md5(id)`? Is it a security issue that the user will find out some ID number?

Comment: I don't think you understand why hash functions are useful and I don't think this question will help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to obscure the id the may I suggest that you use two codes that can be placed before and after in your url.

```
$before_code = "8292273";
```

```
$after_code = "9388347";
```

if you use characters in your id then mix in a few

i'm assuming that $row[0] is your id

```
<a href="view_edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $before_code.$row[0].$after_code; ?>">
  Edit
</a>
```

if you set the before and after codes to a set length you could change them randomly and use `substr` to remove the set number of characters from the beginning and the end to get your id.

if you use set codes then you can use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` to remove the codes leaving your id.

as long as you keep your codes to yourself most will not be able to find the id unless it is that persons ID and they already know what it is... which would make this a waste of time...

Answer (score 0):

Use `mcrypt_encrypt()`  and `mcrypt_decrypt()`  to encrypt and decrypt the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `md5` hash unless it is stored elsewhere against an `$ID` and retrieved. (`md5` is a one-way hashing algorithm: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)).

Your source.php probably needs to look like:

```
<td><a href="view_edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_hash'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Your rendered HTML may look like:

```
<td><a href="view_edit_form.php?id=79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4">Edit</a></td>
```

In your *`source.php`* file AND *`view_edit_form.php`*, you need to make a call to your database (This is more often than not stored in a database) to retrieve the hash (or `$ID`) based on the the `md5` hash in question.

You may be better off using a different hashing algorithm, but md5 is usually acceptable for basic security/obfuscation - but **NOT** for encrypted passwords these days. It's pretty much dependent on what you mean by [security](/questions/tagged/security).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but how to get the `$row['id_hash']`?